Why does rapid page navigation in Blazor cause issues when each page initializes Entity Framework Core?
I'm encountering an issue in my Blazor application where rapid page navigation seems to be causing problems. Each page in my application initializes Entity Framework Core to fetch data from the database. However, if I navigate between pages quickly before Entity Framework Core completes its operation, it causes the page to break, throwing errors like

Invalid attempt to call ReadAsync when reader is closed

I suspect that this issue might be related to the way Blazor handles page initialization and disposal, possibly causing conflicts with Entity Framework Core's database connections.
Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? What could be causing this behavior, and how can I address it to ensure smooth page transitions even with rapid navigation?
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
  Unhandled exception in circuit 'DGk_KNxu7rKw9J-WL_-4ZPD8OV3XvTtepIKWTAk2_GI'.
  System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call ReadAsync when reader is closed.
     at Microsoft.Data.Common.ADP.ExceptionWithStackTrace(Exception e)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at cpServicios.Services.PacientesServices.GetAllPacientes() in C:\Users\PC\Documents\Proyectos\cdeWebApp\cpServicios\Services\Pacientes\PacientesServices.cs:line 51
     at cdeWebApp.Components.Pages.Tablas.TablaPacientes.OnInitializedAsync()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)


https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22932?

You are not showing enough details of your solution, but basically:

When you navigates away from page, ComponentBase.Dispose() might be called before your OnInitializedAsync has finished

your DbContext instance lifetime is limited by your page lifetime, which is not a bad idea in general.


So DbContext gets disposed together with the page before OnInitalizedAsync finishes.
Good idea is to use cancellation tokens when calling async methods from blazor.
For example:
CancellationTokenSource _disposedCts = new();
public void Dispose()
{        
   _disposedCts.Cancel();
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  CancellationToken ct = _disposedCts.CancellationToken;
  try
  {
     _pacientes = await PacientesServices.GetAllPacientes(ct) 
  }
  catch when (ct.CancellationToken.IsCancelled)
  {
     //do nothing
  }
}

However, if you create a new DB Context instance (e.g. using DbContextFactory) each time you call GetAllPacientes(), you won't need to do the cancellation.

As a side note, RX extensions can be helpful here. I wrote a blogbost about it some time ago: https://blog.vyvojari.dev/blazor-take-advantage-of-system-reactive-aka-observables-part-2/

You are disposing your cancellation source before it does its job.

After reading the article I removed _disposedCts.Dispose(), but WTF? Anyway, one more  reason to use Rx

The problem you are facing is common when you handle the database operation. the reason is processing conflict between the navigation of the page and the database query thread. When you navigate rapidly the page may be in progress and database operation has not yet completed that can cause database connection to EF to be closed or the context to be destroyed prematurely when a new page is initialized. to avoid this conflict and use rapid navigation with database there are multiple ways you can use:
1)Cancellation Tokens:
You could use the CancellationToken to cancel an incomplete task while navigating the page.
 private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await LoadData(_cts.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation was cancelled.");
        }
    }
    
    private async Task LoadData(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var data = await _dataService.GetDataAsync(cancellationToken);
        // Process data
    }

private void OnLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Cancel the task      
  _cts.Cancel();
    }

    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _cts.Dispose();
    }

2)Asynchronous processing:
Make sure that all database operations are processed in an asynchronous thread and not blocking the main thread can reduce errors.
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var data = await Task.Run(() => _pacientesService.GetAllPacientes());
//Processing of data
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle exceptions   
 }
}

3)Add a status check to ensure the validity of EF Core objects:
You can check if the context has been closed or destroyed before each EF Core method call:
public async Task<List<Paciente>> GetAllPacientes(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (_context == null || _context.Database.GetDbConnection().State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The database connection is closed");
    }
    return await _context.Pacientes.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}



Why OnLocationChanged? 2. GetAllPacientes() is already asynchronous according to the stacktrace. If it weren't, the navigation would not occur before it returns. Anyway, if you wrapped synchronous call into Task.Run(), you'd  still have the same problem as OP.


@RubénDíazDugo also could you share the code of  cpServicios.Services.PacientesServices.GetAllPacientes() in C:\Users\PC\Documents\Proyectos\cdeWebApp\cpServicios\Services\Pacientes\PacientesServices.cs:line 51
